# Correctly placing views in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a ScrollView, into which I plan a number of views with hexagons drawn on them. The app I am writing will have three versions - each with a different number of hexagons - 25, 64 or 100. The issue is, that I have to introduce fudge factors to get each to layout correctly in the scrollview, so that all hexagons can be accessed. I know what I am doing wrong is probably very basic - but I would appreciate some advice!

The code below is a minimal version of what I have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var hexagons: [Hexagon] = populateHexagonArray(with: 100) //change this number to 25, 64 or 100 for the different layouts
let minHexagonSize: CGFloat = 75

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader
    { scrollViewGeometry in
        ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal], showsIndicators: true)
        {
            let scrollableViewWidth = minHexagonSize * (sqrt(CGFloat(hexagons.count))+sqrt(sqrt(CGFloat(hexagons.count))))
            let scrollableViewHeight = minHexagonSize * (sqrt(CGFloat(hexagons.count)))
            HStack(spacing:-minHexagonSize)
            {
                ForEach(hexagons)
                {hexagon in
                    let thisFrame = getFrameFor(hexagon: hexagon, minWidth:minHexagonSize)
                    Circle()
//remove "- (scrollViewGeometry.size.width * 0.3)" for 25 hexagons build
                        .position(x: thisFrame.origin.x - (scrollViewGeometry.size.width/2) - (scrollViewGeometry.size.width * 0.3), y: scrollViewGeometry.size.height/2 -  thisFrame.origin.y)                       
                        .frame(width: thisFrame.size.width, height: thisFrame.size.height)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: scrollableViewWidth + (scrollableViewWidth*0.25), height: scrollableViewHeight + (scrollableViewHeight*0.5))
        }
    }
}

static func populateHexagonArray(with count: Int) -> [Hexagon]
{
    var array: [Hexagon] = []
    for i in 1...count
    {
        array.append(Hexagon(id: i-1))
    }
    return array
}

func getFrameFor(hexagon: Hexagon, minWidth:CGFloat) -> CGRect
{
    var thisFrame = CGRect()
    var frameWidth = minWidth
    let numberOfHexagonsWide = sqrt(Double(hexagons.count)) + floor(Double(sqrt(Double(hexagons.count))/2))
    let widthOfHexagonViews = (Double(frameWidth) * 0.8) * numberOfHexagonsWide
    let xMargin = (Double(frameWidth) - widthOfHexagonViews) / 12
    var xStartingPosition = 0
    var xPosition = 0
    var yStartingPosition = 1
    var yPosition = 1
    var yEndPosition = 1
    
    let scrollViewAreaWidth = frameWidth * sqrt(CGFloat(hexagons.count))+sqrt(sqrt(CGFloat(hexagons.count)))
    
    let scrollViewAreaHeight = frameWidth * (sqrt(CGFloat(hexagons.count)) + 2)
    
    if minWidth < minHexagonSize
    {
        frameWidth = minHexagonSize
    }
    
    for index in 0...hexagons.count
    {
        var actualXPosition = (Double(xPosition) * (0.5 * Double(frameWidth))) - (0.5 * Double(frameWidth))
        var actualYPosition = Double(yPosition) * (0.8 * Double(frameWidth)) - (0.5 * Double(frameWidth))
        
        actualXPosition -= (Double(scrollViewAreaWidth) * 0.01)
        actualYPosition -= (Double(scrollViewAreaHeight) * 0.01)
        
        thisFrame = CGRect(x: actualXPosition + xMargin, y: actualYPosition, width: Double(frameWidth), height: Double(frameWidth))
        
        if yPosition == yEndPosition
        {
            if Double(yStartingPosition) < sqrt(Double(hexagons.count))
            {
                yStartingPosition += 1
                xStartingPosition += 1
            }
            else
            {
                yEndPosition += 1
                xStartingPosition += 2
            }
            yPosition = yStartingPosition
            xPosition = xStartingPosition
        }
        else
        {
            xPosition += 1
            yPosition -= 1
        }
        
        if hexagon.id == index
        {
            return thisFrame
        }
    }
    return thisFrame
}
}

struct Hexagon: Identifiable
{
    var id: Int
}
```

The problem is, in this standard version without fudge factors, only the layout with 64 hexagons layout correctly - i.e. scrollable to view both extremes in x and y axes, and without excessive amounts of space.

Thank you for your patience - I hope someone is able to advise!

Comment: You've provided *some* code, but not enough for anyone to run. You say you "introduce fudge factors", but you haven't described what they are. You may want to look into including a [mre] and describe the result you're getting vs. the result you're hoping for.

Comment: Apologies for the delay - I have revised my code to a minimal reproducible example. Hopefully it makes sense now...